# SCCM and listing clients with Spotify/Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, spotify, system-administration, sccm, system-center

I'm currently working for a project, where we are actively monitoring installed applications in our Windows environment (We have lot's of Windows 7 Workstations + SCCM 2012)

We are currently struggling to keep track of Spotify, Dropbox and all of these programs that install under user profile. They will show up locally in Add&Remove Programs list, but when using SCCM reports or queries, we cannot get any results anywhere.

Is it possible to detect these installations somehow through SCCM or other methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is not detected by hard or software inventory then it should at least always be possible using software metering.

A detailed guide on how to use it can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg682017.aspx).

The basic steps to make it work are
- Enabling it in the client settings
- Generating a rule under "Assests and Compliance" - "Software Metering"

Note that you can use a * as placeholder for version number.

Answer (score 0):

Before you look to expand your configuration(possibly enabling additional features), run "resource explorer" on one of your SCCM clients that you know this software to be installed on.  Flip through all of the resources inventoried to verify there is no mention of "dropbox".  It's quite possible that installation is might be reflected in a different attribute class than what you are querying.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a comphensive guide, using Spotify as the example on how to inventory and then report and even automatically uninstall using SCCM if you want to take a look at that.

Its a long guide that shows ways of using Power BI, inventory exe files and auto removal, so this is the full article: https://blog.techygeekshome.info/2019/10/remove-spotify/

However, if you just want to report on Spotify, the jist of it is this:

- Open the SCCM Console
- Go to Administration > Overview > Client Settings
- Edit Your Default Device Settings
- Go to Software Inventory
- Click Set Types button
- Click the yellow sun (new) icon
- Type in spotify.exe
- Configure the other settings how you want or leave as default
- Click OK and exit the Settings

Query the collected data then using an SQL query like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
 COMP.UserName0 AS [User],
 COMP.Manufacturer0 AS [Make],
 COMP.Model0 AS [Model],
 COMP.Name0 AS [Computer],
 SYS.SystemType0 AS [Architecture],
 SWI.ModifiedDate AS [Install Date],
 SWF.FileName AS [Filename],
 SWF.FileDescription AS [Product],
 SWF.FileVersion AS [Version]
 FROM v_GS_SYSTEM SYS
 INNER JOIN SoftwareInventory SWI
      on SYS.ResourceID = SWI.ClientId
 INNER JOIN SoftwareFile SWF
      on SWF.ProductId = SWI.ProductId
 INNER JOIN v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM COMP
  on SYS.ResourceID = COMP.ResourceID
 WHERE SWF.FileName = 'spotify.exe'
```